# Stability of the origin of the linear system $\dot{x} = Ax$ given $A^2 = I$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2 = I$. What can you say about the stability of the origin of the linear system $\dot{x} = Ax$? Are there nontrivial stable and/or unstable subspaces?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a start, what can you say about the eigenvalues?

Comment: Here's my attempt at partial solution: $A^2y = Iy = y$, where y is an eigenvector. Then eigenvalues are +1 and -1. Since one of the eigenvalues is positive, the origin is unstable. But how do I find nontrivial stable, unstable subspaces?

Comment: Careful: we don't know that both $+1$ and $-1$ are eigenvalues.  It could be that just one is an eigenvalue.

Comment: If $+1$ is an eigenvalue, the span of a corresponding eigenvector is a nontrivial unstable subspace.  Similarly for $-1$ with stable.

Comment: Very good point .. both eigenvalues are +1, both eigenvalues are -1, or eigenvalues are +1 and -1.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: But what if some eigenvalues are +1 and some are -1 then what would the stable subspace and unstable subspace be? The respective span of corresponding eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes they would.